# audioContext.suspend() not stopping music as expected

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm trying to get some generative music to pause ideally, but I'd settle for stop using Wen Audio Javascript API. The issue I have is that audioContext.suspend() doesn't seem to do anything. All the documentation and examples suggest the following will work, but I can't work out the issue. However, I'm new to javascript so suspect I'm doing something stupid.

All the console logs prove that the function is firing on the second click. I've also tried stop and that also isn't working. I'm using Chrome to test my work, have tried it on Safari, but it doesn't even get as far as playing the track.

```
// for cross browser
const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
const audioContext = new AudioContext();

function startLoop(audioBuffer, pan=0, rate=1) {
    let sourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    let pannerNode = audioContext.createStereoPanner();

    sourceNode.buffer = audioBuffer;
    sourceNode.loop = true;
    sourceNode.loopStart = 11.35;
    sourceNode.loopEnd = 12.1;
    sourceNode.playbackRate.value = rate;
    sourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

    pannerNode.pan.value = pan;

    sourceNode.connect(pannerNode);
    pannerNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

    sourceNode.start(0, 0);
}

function playAudio() {
console.log("playAudio")
fetch('Ambition.mp3')
  .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then(arrayBuffer => audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer))
  .then(audioBuffer => {
    startLoop(audioBuffer,-1);
    startLoop(audioBuffer,1,1.002);
  })
  .catch(e => console.error(e));
}

var playing = "False"

function playOrStop() {
console.log("Playing is set to " + playing)
if (playing === "False") 
    {
    console.log("Play");
    playAudio();
    playing="True";
     }
else {
console.log("Suspend");
```

// THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT DOESN'T WORK

```
audioContext.suspend().then(function() {
      playing="Suspend";
      console.log("Suspend happened")
        })
     }
}

var b1=document.getElementById("playButton1");
b1.onclick = playOrStop;
```

On the second click of the button - 'Suspend happened' is displayed on the log, but the audio isn't suspended.
The first click works as expected.

Comment: From a quick read, I think it should be suspending.  I'd file a bug against your browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I executed your code (with a different MP3) and it worked as expected in Firefox and Chrome. I pressed the button and waited for the sound begin. After a few seconds I pressed the button again and the sound stopped.

But I think you ran into a subtle bug/feature in Chrome. When the autoplay policy was implemented in Chrome it was intended to be as backwards compatible as possible. This is why calling `start()` on an `AudioScheduledSourceNode` can also resume a suspended context.

If you press the button twice and the first promise has not yet resolved, then your code calls `audioContext.suspend()` before calling `sourceNode.start()`. Even though the call to `suspend()` works any subsequent call to `start()` on an `AudioScheduledSourceNode` will set the context's state back to running.

Firefox handles this differently and the consensus is that Firefox is right in this case. The spec was already changed to reflect that (https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/pull/1823) and it will most likely get fixed in a future version of Chrome. But it can of course never hurt to file a bug. https://new.crbug.com

If you want to prevent the `sourceNode` from resuming the AudioContext you could check the `state` of the context before calling `start()`.

```
if (audioContext.state === 'running') {
    sourceNode.start(0, 0);
}
```

Your example doesn't work in Safari because it doesn't support the `StereoPannerNode`. I do recommend to use standardized-audio-context (https://github.com/chrisguttandin/standardized-audio-context) for better cross browser compatibility as I'm the author of that library. :-) It also comes with a `StereoPannerNode` implementation that works in Safari.

Comment: Thanks Chris - that helped. I moved to Safari and tried it there and it did work. Good to know I wasn't going crazy.